# .NET photo processing component

Tags: .net, image-processing, camera, photo, imaging

I'm looking for a .NET image processing component or an open source alternative to automate the following tasks:

- Photo capture (webcams and photo cameras)
- Photo printing (grid/strip modes)
- Applying photo effects
- Saving photos

AtalaSoft DotImage is quite expensive, any other suggestions are welcome.

Thanks J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the [AForge library](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/), it's free, open source and has a large [list of features](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/) and [applications](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/wiki/Features).

There's also a nice article on `The Code Project` about it, see [Image Processing Lab in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx)

[image: sample image of AForge image processing]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used AForge, but I've seen it mentioned a bit on this topic. My choice would be one of the OpenCV wrappers like [EMGU](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).